# Start process depending on background process

Tags: java, linux, shell, jboss, jenkins

There are some tests that are ran in an application server (JBoss); we want to integrate these tests in Jenkins.

In Jenkins there are these steps (all steps are Ant steps):

- ... (other steps)
- start server in background
- run tests
- stop server
- ... (other steps)

The server needs to be started in background in order to let the following tasks to do their job. I have written the following script to mimic this:

```
export LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
./run.sh &
sleep 400
cd /testTriggerLocation
ant run-tests
kill `cat $jBossHome/4.0.5/bin/jboss.pid`
```

run.sh starts the server and after it is started it stores the JVM process id in jboss.pid.

In the normal way (a foreground process) JBoss takes about ~100 s to starts but in here it takes a value dependent on the argument of sleep. If I put 200 s it takes between ~ 190 - 210 s, if it is 300 s it takes 290 - 310 s; the problem is that if the tests are triggered before the server is started they obviously fail. Is there a way to synchronize this? Or maybe another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to fork run.sh?

Comment: Does the run.sh or what ever it starts produce a log?  If so you could have something in here that watches for something in that log.. say "started" or whatever it prints out saying its ready to go... then let the script continue.. rather than just a sleep.

Comment: @EarlGray Because if it would be a foreground process it would ran indefinitely in Jenkins and then the tests would not be ran.

Comment: @jco.owens Actually when it finishes it writes in `jboss.pid` file; thanks for the tip, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into using a simple process manager such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [God](http://godrb.com/) which can daemonize processes for you while you run your tests.

In my case, using God I would run:

```
 god -c my-project.god
 ruby test-runner.rb
 god terminate
```